# Angular UI grid search/filter feature : Strange behavior with null in search string

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

Our application uses Angular-UI grid. If the values are null for a column (which the UI-grid displays as blank) for all the rows in grid and if we search with string "null" or combinations of character sequence of string null (like "nu", "nul"), rows were displayed. How to disable matching blank against null in ui-grid?